# Ionic 5 - ion-item requires 2 clicks in IOS to trigger onclick event

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5, ion-item

Below code is using to open modal on click of ion-item

```
 <ion-item lines="none" (click)="selectDepartment()" class="m-0 ion-float-left w100">
   <ion-input formControlName="department_name" ngDefaultControl readonly type="text" placeholder="Select Department" class="tenx-input with-icon header-sub-head-font-16 w100 ion-float-left">
        <ion-icon class="header-sub-head-font-16" src="assets/icon/down-arrow.svg" item-right></ion-icon>
   </ion-input>
 </ion-item>
```

"selectDepartment" gets triggered only if user clicks on ion-item 2nd time.
Tried many solutions but no luck

Ionic Info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\Nitin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 12 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.12.1
   native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Android\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.17.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.11.3
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: and what happens if you put the click on the ion-input element? also it would be useful if you posted your component code or at least the selectDepartment method.

Comment: dont know it wil solve your issue or not but try `(tap)="yourFunction()"`

Comment: @E.Maggini selectDepartment method only has console.. it will console only on second click

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I tried "tap" method but still not working in iOS (giving same result as "click")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work around for this could be:

- Disable the ion-item
- Add onClick the ion-item
- Prevent the default

It works for me always.